# Knockout JS Using IF statement and With Statement listen for click event

Tags: if-statement, knockout.js, onclicklistener

The input field should be empty on page load.

When the user clicks the 'Edit Post' then I call KO click and 'select' function (all working) .. when I do this call the row selected is bound correctly.

Current code automatically binds on page load so the first record is in the input field.

```
<div data-bind="with: Selected">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" />
</div>
<i title="Edit Post" data-bind="click: $parent.select"></i>
```

**Example hack**

```
<div data-bind="if **click: $parent.select then** with: Selected">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" />
</div>

<i title="Edit Post" data-bind="click: $parent.select"></i>
```

How do I write a data-bind if 'click' then do 'with: Select' ?

**Update**

Add example code:  http://jsfiddle.net/uC8Vt/70/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would just want this to work off of the `Selected` observable. If it is not populated, then it won't render the area.  If it is pooulated, then whatever object that `Selected` holds will be used.

So, when you call `$parent.select` you would want to populate `Selected` with your object.

In fact, observables are functions, so unless you need to run other logic, you can even take a shortcut and bind your `click` directly against the `Selected` observable. The current data is passed as the first argument, which sets the value of the observable.

Comment: RP - Initially I need the field displayed as ADD NAME .. then when the user selects a row to edit, we call the *Selected* now it is EDIT NAME. By using the *with Selected* the entire div is hidden on initial load.

Comment: Maybe you can throw something in jsFiddle? I am not sure that I am entirely clear on your overall structure. You can certainly use the `ifnot` binding against `Selected` to display something when `Selected` is null/undefined.

Comment: got a sample up on jFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/pomber/uC8Vt/60/  I would like the Business Name area visible the entire time so users can ADD a new record or EDIT a selected record.

Comment: I might go with something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/zKMdB/ where you use the same Name field for new and existing records and then either update the selected record or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You would change the Selected property depending on the item clicked...

So an example viewModel might be like...

```
var items = [{ Name: 'item1' }, { Name: 'item2' }];

var viewModel = {
    items: items,
    Selected: ko.observable(items[0])
}

viewModel.select = function(selectedItem) {
    // The first arg is the context of the item clicked
    // Selected in an observable
    viewModel.Selected(selectedItem);
};
```

Then, as Selected changes... your Name binding will automatically update.